# What statistical/statistical analysis can I use to extract information from set of words?

Tags: natural-language

I have long (thousands) lists of words set. A set of words is usually combination of a number and unit of measurement, but it can also be a combination of words. What kind of analysis can I use to summarize and extract the underlying information?

Example 1:

```
List:

...
1000 MB/s
1.000 MBps
1,000 MBps
1000,00 MBps
1000.00MBps
1000 mbps (wrongly written unit)
8000 mbps
1000000 Kbps
1000Megabyte/s
...

Expected result:
 - value: 1000
 - unit: Mbps
```

Example 2:

```
List:

...
Android 4.4 KitKat
Android Kitkat 4.4
Android v4.4
Android version 4.4 codename KitKat
Android - 4.4
Android 4.4, KitKat
Android KitKat
Android 4.4.4 Kitkat (Outliar)
KitKat 4.4
Nestle KitKat (wrong)
...

Expected result:
 - type: Android
 - version: 4.4
 - codename: KitKat
```

It is easy for humans to normalize such variations in natural language and understand the original message. How can I make computers do something like this?

Comment: As described, this problem is too hard for a computer to solve. In the Android example, how would a computer get the names "type", "version", and "codename"? The only way a human could've come up with those names is by using their prior knowledge about software versions, concerning how to recognize and interpret a version name. If your thousands of lists are as heterogeneous as the two examples, you'd need a separate piece of such extra knowledge for every list.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment. If I can provide the properties such as "Operating system", "Version" and "Codename" will it make it easier for a computer to solve the problem?

Comment: That's much easier, but maybe still not 100% doable. I think you could write a program that could take one of these big lists and a number of chunks *N* to find (say, 3, in the case of the Android example) and then return the chunks. The implementation would be basically: split each item in the list across word boundaries and return the *N* most frequent substrings thus produced. But I don't see how given the names "Operating system", "Version", and "Codename", the program could figure out which chunk goes with which name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Wolfram Alfa.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000%20MB%2Fs%201.000%20MBps%201%2C000%20MBps%201000%2C00%20MBps%201000.00MBps%201000%20mbps%20%208000%20mbps%201000000%20Kbps%201000Megabyte%2Fs) I have put your example and it could make some sense out of it:

> {Quantity[1000, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1000, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"] 1000, Quantity[0, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1000, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1000, "Megabits"/"Seconds"] Quantity[8000, "Megabits"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1×10^6, "Kilobits"/"Seconds"] Quantity[1000, "Megabytes"/"Seconds"]}